# UI Router Backbutton causes re-request of all assets in index.html but prefixed with the route html5mode

Tags: angularjs, node.js, html, express, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular with UI router and Express.

I have set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`

and have `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` of my `index.html` file.

On my server I have a catchall route that sends `index.html` if the request does not match one of my existing api or asset routes.

```
app.route('/*')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      console.log('the req.url', req.url);
      console.log('sending index.html', path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(app.get('appPath') + '/index.html'));
    });
```

In 90% of cases this works very well. Users are able to navigate through states using `$state.go` and refresh those states with the browser refresh button.

However, If I navigate to `stateA` then to `stateB` then to `stateC` and then hit the `browser back button` the app successfully transitions back to `stateB` and then makes ajax requests for all of the assets in `index.html` but prefixed with the route for `stateB` the result is a long stream of errors which cause the app to crash.

[image]

These errors are due to the fact that my server is responding to these requests by sending `index.html` over and over again and the requests are for `.js` files ... here is the server log

[image]

notice how after I send `index.html` the front end makes requests for all the assets in `index.html` but prefixed with the route so I am getting requests for `onboard-introbower_components/*` instead of `bower_components/*`. Note that this does not happen when I refresh the browser when it is pointed to `/onboard-intro` I simply get one request and send `index.html` and it works.

[image]

I have done many hours of research and could not find another SO question that matched this situation. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after more some digging I solved this problem.

What was happening was that I had included `jQuery mobile` in my project to handle touch events. `jQuery mobile` also handles `client side routing` and was conflicting with `UI Router`. I found an article about how to disable `jQuery mobile`'s routing here 
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-To-Disable-jQuery-Mobile-Routing-While-Working-Along-With-BackboneJS-2626.php

The author is implementing this solution for `Backbone` but it also works for `Angular`. All you need to do is run

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

   $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;

   $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

   $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;

   $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;

});
```

`BEFORE` you include `jQuery mobile` in your angular project. This will turn off `jquery mobile` client side routing and allow `UI Router` to do its thing.